# Nokia Lumia 1020 factory reset

Tags: lumia, windows-live, nokia-lumia-1020, reset

I just bought a Lumia and I want to return it because it has a display-related manufacturing issue.

I've used my Windows account (Outlook, OneDrive, etc) with it. If I reset to factory settings, will this also have an impact on my windows account? Will it erase/delete OneDrive files?

I assume no, but I just want to double check it.

Comment: Would you briefly describe your "display-related manufacturing issue". I have a 1020 and am curious if it's something that affects all 1020s

Comment: Sure. I had two problems actually. First one, which I'm pretty ok with: when the phone is in sleep/inactive mode, on the dark screen you would see some darker spots (http://forums.wpcentral.com/attachments/nokia-lumia-1020/42663d1378772528t-img.jpg). The second one: I had two strange shadows on the bottom of the screen. They were theere all the time, but would become noticeable when the screen was lit/there were bright colors on it, such as white. The guys from the store acknowledged it was a manufacturing issue, and gave me a new one instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Windows Phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10666/windows-phone-reset-my-phone) site:

> Resetting your Windows Phone will return it to the same state it was
>   in the first time you turned it on. All your personal content will be
>   erased, and the phone will be restored to its factory settings.
>
> If you decide to reset your phone, you can back up apps, text messages,
>   photos and more to your Microsoft account in the cloud beforehand.

Resetting your phone resets your phone only and not the accounts connected to your phone.

So no, you will not lose your OneDrive files that are in the cloud.