# What is the difference between hard reset and soft reset?

Tags: 8.0, reset, soft-reset

I am Nokia Lumia 520 Windows Phone user. At present internet is not working on my phone but the notification area on the home screen does show the 3G symbol. Someone told me there is a problem in my network settings so first do soft reset and perhaps a hard reset.

What are a hard reset and a soft reset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokia Lumia 1020 factory reset](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/nokia-lumia-1020-factory-reset)

Comment: You add two questions here what and how. I have removed the 'how to perform' question since others have pointed out that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

**The soft reset :**

A soft reset can be done very easy on a Windows Phone. You have to hold the on-off switch of the smartphone for a few seconds and then select ” To turn of slide downward” Now the smartphone is turned off and can be switched on again, press the on or off switch.

**The hard reset:**

If the soft reset does not work you have to run the hardreset to turn the phone back to the factory settings.

How to do a software hard reset :
The software hard reset is by Windows Phone smartphones every time the same. You have to go to he “Settings ” and click on “Info” . Now you click on the “Reset phone” button. After a restart of the smartphone, you return to the Setup Menu of Windows Phone and can enter their data again .

The hardware hard reset can be done with the hardware buttons of your smartphone:

Once nothing works, not even the software hard reset function, you can run the button shortcut of the smartphone to get it to the manufacturer-settings.

To do a hard reset you have to:

- Press the “On- or Off button”, till the smartphone switches of.
- When the smartphone is switching on again, add the “Volume down button” to the holding of the power button. till you will see a explanation of how to reset the phone on the display. Now you can lift the buttons.
  -Press this buttons now in the following direction “Volume up -> Volume down -> Power-Button -> Volume down”
- Now the smartphone will do a reset and restart the system.