# What am I going to lose if I hard reset my phone?

Tags: reset

After choosing an easy-to-remember password for my Lumia 1020's wallet, I promptly forgot the password.  It would be nice if I could just delete the wallet and start over, but apparently the only way to reset the wallet is to hard reset the whole phone.

I know a lot of stuff, such as my photos, gets backed up to OneDrive.  What am I going to lose if I hard reset my phone?

In other words, what are the big things that aren't backed up, and that I should take care to back up myself before I do a hard reset?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nokia Lumia 1020 factory reset](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/nokia-lumia-1020-factory-reset)

Comment: @Indrek, possible, yes, but I was hoping for more detail than that, preferably from someone who's actually done it before.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely will lose data stored in apps.

Check for if the photos uploaded from OneDrive are highest quality, and if not, you may want to manually copy them via USB.

Another thing you might want to copy the Screenshots folder, Documents folder - in short copy all the folders you see when you connect your phone to PC.

Also you might want to verify if SMS backup is ON, to ensure that it does get backed up/and restored after you reset the phone. Also just ensure App+Settings backup is on.

Read more about this [here on WP website](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-CA/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/back-up-my-stuff).